# Not able to generating empty array/slice of golang code using protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-gateway

We want to return one object/struct with one property as empty list/array/slice in golang to client(browser).
from the go code we are returning empty slice of len=0 and capacity=0, but through protobuf this key is getting deleted or set as a nil and removed.

> [protobuf code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3)

```
syntax = "proto3";
package version1;
message ToDo {
     int64 id = 1 ;
     string title = 2;
}
message ReadAllResponse{
     repeated   ToDo  toDos = 1 ;
}
```

> golang code:

```
list := make([]*version1.ToDo, 0) //[]*version1.ToDo{}
output:= version1.ReadAllResponse{
        ToDos: list,
        Api:   "v1",
    }
```

I am getting actual output as  `{api: "v1"}` but expected should come as `{api: "v1",todos:[]}`

Please help/suggest us in fixing the protobuf or golang syntax.

Comment: Are you calling your grpc service directly from the browser (with grpc-web or something), or are you calling grpc-gateway (https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) ?

Comment: I am calling the service as http end point from browser and backend proxy this request through grpc-gateway .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your array field gets lost when [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) serializes the proto struct to json with jsonpb serializer.

Fortunately the gateway exposes a way to configure the jsonpb serializer when setting up the gateway:

```
mux := runtime.NewServeMux(runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard, &runtime.JSONPb{ EmitDefaults:true}))
```

The  `&runtime.JSONPb{ EmitDefaults:true}` option should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was big help.

Comment: for the future Reference of issue.. https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/233 . https://jbrandhorst.com/post/gopherjs-client-grpc-server-4/